# Location div at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I succeeded to put div at the bottom with this code:

```
#div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Recently, I added a side-bar to my site (300px).
When the side-bar opens, the whole site move left 300px, except for the div in the bottom.

I found that if I delete the `position: absolute;` from the css, the div will move left like all the elements in the site, but the div will not be in the bottom.

There is a way to move the div when the sidebar open like the all site and also be in the bottom of the page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post a plunkr with your code?

Comment: What do you mean? The html code of the div? @CarlAmbroselli

Comment: A non-working example snippet to show your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
}
```

If you want to center divs inside a div ,there's an example 
HTML

```
   <div class="parent">
            <div class="children"></div>
            <div class="children"></div>
            <div class="children"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 div.parent{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:25px;
    text-align:center;
}

div.children{
    border:2px solid blue;
    background-color:orange;
    width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:250px;
}
```

Other way to center only 1 div inside another div looks like that

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
        <div class="children">Woho</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.parent{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:25px;
}

div.children{
    border:2px solid blue;
    background-color:orange;
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

The `margin:0 auto;` property makes your div to go in the center.

Comment: Thank you. It's work. Can you tell me how to center the elemnts in the div without using (width: 100%), because when the sidebar clicked, the width changed. Thanks!

Comment: @Roy If I helped you , please mark my answer as checked. So what's your other question , how to center the text in a div tag or other divs inside a div?

Comment: Center other divs inside a div @Nasco.Chachev